# Report Index Not Filtering Properly Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a subreport in Access 2010 that lists projects in an index based on criteria from a search form. In this form, the user can select a variety of parameters to search for (ex. Project number, area, project year, etc...).

I set up an SQL to filter the projects that match the search criteria. Right now, it will work only for project number; It brings up a project if I filter for it directly, otherwise it brings every single project regardless of the other search parameters.

The index has to be able to be filtered by ProjNo *and* by all other criteria (project year, area, dept, designer, etc...)

```
SELECT * FROM INDEX WHERE INDEX.ProjNo LIKE 
IIF(Forms![SearchForm]![ProjNo]="","*",Forms![SearchForm]![ProjNo])
```

I'm not very good at SQL, so any advice would be great.

Comment: The rows which match all the criteria. So if they search by, say, area and project year, it should bring everything that matches both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want ...

> The rows which match all the criteria. So if they search by, say, area
>   and project year, it should bring everything that matches both.

Use one `WHERE` clause condition to specify you want to match on *area* and another condition for *project year*.  Combine the two conditions with `AND`.

Assuming your *SearchForm* includes a textbox named *txtArea* for the *area* value and another named *txtProjectYear* for the *project year* value ...

```sql
SELECT * FROM [INDEX] AS i 
WHERE
        i.area = Forms![SearchForm]![txtArea]
    AND i.[project year] = Forms![SearchForm]![txtProjectYear]
```

Note `INDEX` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#I).  I bracketed it in the SQL statement, which should reduce the potential for problems.  However, if it were me, I would give the table a different name.

Comment: How would I do this for all the filters? There's more than just those two.

Comment: `AND` a third condition for the third search criterion.  Repeat as needed for each remaining criterion.

Comment: When I do this, a pop-up comes up and asks me for i.project year even though that's filled in in the search form, and brings up a blank report.

Comment: Does your table include a field named *project year*?  If so, you must bracket that name because it contains a space: `i.[project year]`  Note I forgot to include the dot in my original answer.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM INDEX WHERE INDEX.ProjNo LIKE 
IIF(Len(Forms![SearchForm]![ProjNo])>0,Forms![SearchForm]![ProjNo],"*")
```

Of course, you could evaluate the contents of your form in vba & determine whether you should apply a filter, something like (untested)

```
Dim strProject As String, strQuery as string
If Me.ProjNo.Selected > 0 Then
    strProject = Me.ProjNo
Else
    strProject = "*"
End If
strQuery = "SELECT * FROM INDEX WHERE INDEX.ProjNo LIKE " & Chr(34) & strProject & Chr(34)
```

Then you could use that to build up your filtering expression.

Comment: This didn't work. It returns all the projects even if I search for a specific one.

Comment: OK.  Have you tried the second suggestion - doing the evaluation in vba before applying the filter?

Comment: I've already tried doing it like this in VBA and it didn't work, which is why I'm trying with SQL.